# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components).. but got: undefined, while using mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

I got this error while mounting component to test.

**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports**

```
import React from "react";
import {configure} from "enzyme";
import mount from "enzyme/mount"
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import enTranslations from "../../translations/en.json";
import CharacteristicTable from "./characteristicTable";

    describe("<CharacteristicTable /> component", () => {
      let wrapper;
      beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(
          <IntlProvider locale="en" messages={enTranslations}>
            <CharacteristicTable {...props} />
          </IntlProvider>
        );
      });
    
      it("Should render without exploding", () => {
        expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
      });
    }
```

versionS:

1. react: 16.17.0
2. npm: 8.15.0
3. "enzyme": "^3.11.0"
4. "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6"
5. "jest": "^29.3.1",
6. "jest-cli": "^29.3.1",
7. "jest-junit": "^14.0.0"
8. "jest-react-hooks-shallow": "^1.5.1"

Comment: The error message is clear.

Comment: Its giving error for the library mount from enzyme... what might be the issue?